# How can I use hangfire with an existing entity framework code first application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, hangfire

I'm working in an application that uses entity framework code first approach and is supports sub domains too, means based on the sub domain it takes a connection string for that client (have separate database for each client). For implementing background jobs I'm using **Hangfire**. Currently using separate DB for Hangfire.

**Now my requirement is that I need to create this Hangfire tables into the clients database**. For that I passed the connection string of the clients db to hangfire:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connection string");
```

**But the problem is entity framework trying to drop my data base, I don't want to do this, because it has already valid data of client**.

```
public DataContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString){
        Database.SetInitializer(new DataSeeder());
        Database.Initialize(false);
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

Above is my Datacontext's constructor.

Seeder is like this:

```
public class DataSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>{

}
```

Comment: And why EF tries to drop databases? Did you change your model?

Comment: no, that's the issue I'm facing, i didn't changed my model, but still it is trying to delete.

Comment: Do you use migrations for the main database?

Comment: No, i'm not using migrations

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that after added Hangfire and issuing a "dnx ef migrations add ", and examining the migration file generated, that it also wanted to drop my Identity tables.

I simply edited the migration c# script that was generated and removed those commands from the "Up" method, and everything was working fine.  Perhaps trying this would solve your issue before performing the update to the database.